# Getting Milliseconds elapsed between arbitrary date and Epoch time

Tags: c#, datetime, date-math

If I write a simple method to return the milliseconds between epoch time and `DateTime.UtcNow`, I get a proper answer.  However, if I write a method to return the milliseconds between some arbitrary date and epoch time, the last three digits are always zero. 'Some arbitrary date' means that I pass in to the method the output of DateTime.Parse("arbitrary date string").  As near as I can make out, the DateTime object returned by .Parse is not returning all the significant digits.

Test method:

```
    static void GetMillis()
        {
            DateTime dUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc);
            double utcmillis = (dUtc - epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
            String timestamp = dUtc.ToString();
            DateTime arbitrary = (DateTime.Parse(timestamp));
            Console.WriteLine("Milliseconds between DateTime.UtcNow {0} \nand epoch time {1} are {2}", dUtc, epoch, utcmillis);
            Console.WriteLine("Milliseconds between arbitrary date {0} \nand epoch time {1} are {2}", arbitrary, epoch, (arbitrary - epoch).TotalMilliseconds);
        }
```

Output:

```
C:\src\vs\epochConverter\epochConverter\bin\Debug
{powem} [54] --> .\epochConverter.exe -debug
Milliseconds between DateTime.UtcNow 8/26/2012 11:12:31 PM
and epoch time 1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM are 1346022751385.8
Milliseconds between arbitrary date 8/26/2012 11:12:31 PM
and epoch time 1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM are 1346022751000
```

I don't know if I'm doing something grotesquely wrong or not understanding the math here. I've researched in MSDN and can't find anything relating to this difference.  I really would like to be able to compute the millis as described -- is it possible?

Thanks.

mp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to examine the intermediate values of:

```
String timestamp = dUtc.ToString();
```

Just what it returns will depend on your local settings, but it'll be something like `8/26/2012 11:12:31`, which is only accurate to the nearest second.

Parsing that of course gives a date-time with 0 milliseconds.

It is therefore correct that your milliseconds-since-epoch method has zeros at that point.

If however you did something like:

```
arbitrary = new DateTime(2012, 8, 26, 11, 12, 31, 123);
```

You'd get those 123 milliseconds influencing the result. You can also use a `ToString` and a `ParseExact` that includes fractions of a second, or a whole slew of other ways of obtaining a DateTime.

In all, your milliseconds-since-epoch worked perfectly, but your way of getting a date to test it was flawed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I guess the challenge is flawed thinking.  Because I want the millisecond _difference_ between the two dates and any given date must be representable as a number of millis.  But, I guess, that's not really what is happening with DateTime math.  The use case is for a date string in the demonstrated format to be converted to the DateTime object and then processed.  I have looked at the MSDN article, "How to: Display Milliseconds in Date and Time Values," but I have not been able to make that work for me.

Comment: If the use-case requires you to parse a string, then the `000` at the end is likely fine. It could just be due to milliseconds-since-1970 being a common internal representation for dates in some systems, and relates to that.

Comment: After thinking about it I believe I have gotten a better understanding of what actually happens when the date math is computed.  I have a tool which is supposed to be producing values in _epoch time_ but some times get spewed out in millis and some in seconds.  This is obviously a bug but it's a black box to me.  The end of all this questioning is to make the simplest possible tool for compute these differentials.  I don't like doing things that I don't understand how they work.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The default `DateTime.ToString()` format *does not include* the milliseconds and this is where the data is being lost; it happens *before* the `Parse`. To obtain the milliseconds in the string representation, use a custom format:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
// -> 8/26/2012 11:37:24 PM
DateTime.Parse("8/26/2012 11:37:24 PM").Millisecond
// -> 0

DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK") 
// -> 2012-08-26T23:41:17.3085938Z
DateTime.Parse("2012-08-26T23:41:17.3085938Z").Millisecond
// -> 308
```

See [The Round-trip ("O", "o") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Roundtrip)
 to type less. Or, in this case, consider avoiding the conversion entirely :-)

The math is sound.

Answer (score 0):

The math looks reasonable here.  Don't forget there are 1000 milliseconds in a 1 second, so any date computation from an arbitrary time that does not include milliseconds vs an almost identical time that includes milliseconds will have an error of +/- 1000 milliseconds.